# Why 'аnd' == 'and' is false?

Tags: ruby, text, character-encoding

I tagged character-encoding and text because I know if you type `'and' == 'and'` into the rails console, or most any other programming language, you will get `true`. However, I am having the issue when one of my users pastes his text into my website, I can't spell check it properly or verify it's originality via copyscape because of some issue with the text. (or maybe my understanding of text encoding?)

**EXAMPLE:**

If you copy and paste the following line into the rails console you will get `false`.

```
'аnd' == 'and' #=> false
```

If you copy and paste the following line into the rails console you will get `true` even though they appear exactly the same in the browser.

```
'and' == 'and' #=> true
```

The difference is, in the first example, the first `'аnd'` is copied and pasted from my user's text that is causing the issues. All the other instances of `'and'` are typed into the browser.

Is this an encoding issue?
How to fix my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn’t really an encoding problem, in the first case the strings compare as false simply because *they are different*.

The first character of the first string isn’t a ”normal“ `a`, it is actually [`U+0430 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0430/index.htm) — the first two bytes (208 and 176, or `0xD0` and `0xB0` in hex) are the UTF-8 encoding for this character. It just happens to look exactly like a “normal” Latin `a`, which is [`U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm).

Here’s the “normal” a: `a`, and this is the Cyrillic a: `а`, they appear pretty much identical.

The fix for this really depends on what you want your application to do. Ideally you would want to handle all languages, and so you might want to just leave it and rely on users to provide reasonable input.

You could replace the character in question with a latin `a` using e.g. `gsub`. The problem with that is there are many other characters that have similar appearance to the more familiar ones. If you choose this route you would be better looking for a library/gem that did it for you, and you might find you’re too strict about conversions.

Another option could be to choose a set of Unicode scripts that your application supports and refuse any characters outside those scripts. You can check fairly easily for this with Ruby‘s regular expression script support, e.g. `/\p{Cyrillic}/` will match all Cyrillic characters.

Comment: Damn you! 26 seconds faster! :-D +1

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing up this issue for me. Since I run an english-only writing site I will probably disallow characters outside a chosen set of Unicode scripts. I might try and see how translation goes, but either way a big thanks to you!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not with encodings. A single file or a single terminal can only have a single encoding. If you copy and paste both strings into the same source file or the same terminal window, they will get inserted with the same encoding.

The problem is also not with normalization or folding.

The first string has 4 octets: `0xD0 0xB0 0x6E 0x64`. The first two octets are a two-octet UTF-8 encoding of a single Unicode codepoint, the third and fourth octets are one-octet UTF-8 encodings of Unicode code points.

So, the string consists of three Unicode codepoints: `U+0430 U+006E U+0064`.

These three codepoints resolve to the following three characters:

1. CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
2. LATIN SMALL LETTER N
3. LATIN SMALL LETTER D

The second string has 3 octets: `0x61 0x6E 0x64`. All three octets are one-octet UTF-8 encodings of Unicode code points.

So, the string consists of three Unicode codepoints: `U+0061 U+006E U+0064`.

These three codepoints resolve to the following three characters:

1. LATIN SMALL LETTER A
2. LATIN SMALL LETTER N
3. LATIN SMALL LETTER D

Really, there is no problem *at all*! The two strings *are* different. With the font you are using, a cyrillic a looks the same as a latin a, but as far as Unicode is concerned, they are two different characters. (And in a different font, they might even look different!) There's really nothing you can do from an encoding or Unicode perspective, because the problem is not with encodings or Unicode.

This is called a [homoglyph](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph), two characters that are different but have the same (or very similar) glyphs.

What you *could* try to do is transliterate all strings into Latin (provided that you can guarantee that nobody ever wants to enter non-Latin characters), but really, the questions are:

1. Where does that cyrillic a come from?
2. Maybe it was *meant* to be a cyrillic a and really *should* be treated not-equal to a latin a?

And depending on the answers to those questions, you might either want to fix the source, or just do nothing at all.

This is a very hot topic for browser vendors, BTW, because nowadays someone could register the domain `google.com` (with one of the letters switched out for a homoglpyh) and you wouldn't be able to spot the difference in the address bar. This is called a homograph attack. That's why they always display the Punycode domain in addition to the Unicode domain name.

Comment: A big thanks you you too! Sorry this was just seconds later. Also, Matt's answer was a little more to what I was looking for, but then there was no way for you to know that because my question was so vague. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is eccoding issue, you can have a try like this.

```
irb(main):010:0> 'and'.each_byte {|b| puts b}
97
110
100
=> "and"

irb(main):011:0> 'аnd'.each_byte {|b| puts b} #copied and
208
176
110
100
=> "аnd"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful in that it answers my first question and lets me know that I do need to go down the path of fixing the character encoding. Any ideas of how to correct it in my ruby code? Or even what information I need to provide to get a more specific answer? I'll mark this answer as accepted if I don't get anything more specific because it really does answer my title question. Thanks!

Comment: @user2726983 one `а` is a [cyrillic letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)), it looks identical but has a different unicode code point. It's not a wrong encoding, just a wrong character.